# Relation between Laplace transform and measures.

Tags: measure-theory, laplace-transform

The Laplace transform of a measure $\mu$ on the real line is defined by
$$f_{\mu}(s)= \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-st}d\mu(t), \hspace{1cm} \forall s \geqslant 0.$$
My question is ----

1)Does the Laplace transform of a measure (finite or infinite) always exists?

2)If not, can it be said that the Laplace transform of a probability measure always exists?

If the support of the measure is changed from the real line to the non-negative part of the real line, what happens to question (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of the Laplace transform will not converge in general, because if $\mu$ has support on the whole real line then the exponential term can blow up, depending on the exact form of $\mu$.

The common definition of the Laplace transform is for measures supported on the non-negative real line.
(Alternatively you may want to look into the definition of the two-sided Laplace transform, where $t$ in the exponential is replaced by $|t|$.)

Now, consider a $\mu$ that is supported on the non-negative real line, and that is w.l.o.g. positive.
Since $e^{-st} \le 1$ for $\Re[s]>0$, it is easy to see that

$|f_\mu(s)| \le f_\mu(0) = \int\limits_0^\infty d\mu(t) = \| \mu \|$.

Hence, if the measure is finite, then its Laplace transform exists.
In conclusion, the Laplace transform of a probability measure always exists.
(It is in fact (related to) the measure's moment generating function.)

For infinite measures, one needs some regularity conditions on $\mu$ that ensure that the integral does not blow up.
One of these would be for example, that its distribution function $F(t) := \mu([0,t))$ is exponentially bounded.
That means:

$ \exists K,C > 0: \;\; |F(t)| \le C e^{Kt}$

Then one can show that the Laplace transform exists for $\Re[s]>K$.

Comment: Your first paragraph seems to be incorrect. The integral defined in the question converges for the Gaussian, for example, even though it has support on the whole real line. Additionally, the absolute value $|t|$ doesn't appear in the definition of the two-sided Laplace transform that I'm familiar with.

Comment: In fact, it will converge at $s=0$ for any measure with a finite integral, since $s=0$ just gives the integral of the measure, and the question just becomes, under which circumstances will it converge for some/all other values of $s$. (Note that one doesn't usually expect the Laplace transform to converge for all values of $s$.)

Comment: I stated that his definition will "in general not exist". Surely there are measures for which it does. (As you just have demonstrated.) But to show this you will need additional regularity conditions on $\mu$. In particular you need to require that it decays faster than some exponential as $t\to\pm \infty$. Similar to the statement in my last paragraph.

Comment: But this would essentially be a paraphrasing of "pick a measure for which the integral exists".

Comment: I guess it's just a language thing then. "In general, not X" means "there exist counterexamples to X," but "In general, X" can mean "always X". Your first sentence read "In general [it] will diverge...", followed by a necessary condition for divergence, which sounded like it was meant as a sufficient one. I hope you don't mind if I fix it.

Answer (score 2):

If $\mu$ has density $\frac 1 {\pi (1+x^{2})}$ the the Laplace transform exists only for $s=0$.

Answer (score 0):

When the integral (with respect to the parameter $t$) is over the entire real line it is customary to talk about the Fourier transform. A related notion is that of the characteristic function and not of the moment generating function.

Elaborating on Kavi Rama Murphy response, the Laplace transform of a measure $\mu$ with Cauchy density does not exist on the non-negative real half line but only trivially at $t=0$. The non-existence can perhaps be intuited -if not deduced- from the fact that the first moment of $\mu$ is infinite. I would imagine that for infinite measure the Laplace transform does not exist unless there are certain regularity conditions.